How to write text on the right side in an inverted geometric reference frame with p5
In p5, axis y points downwards. This code make it point upwads (and make the 0,0 the center)
type gridRange={
    xrange:{
        min: number,
        max: number,
    },
    yrange:{
        min: number,
        max: number,
    }
};



const setCoordinateSystem =(r :gridRange,p : p5) =>{
    let xscalingCoeff = window.innerWidth / (r.xrange.max - r.xrange.min);
    let yscalingCoeff = window.innerHeight / (r.yrange.max - r.yrange.min) * -1; // MAKE y points upwards
    let xcenter = r.xrange.max ;
    let ycenter = r.xrange.min ; //NOT AN ERROR!
    p.scale(xscalingCoeff, yscalingCoeff);
    p.translate(xcenter, ycenter);

};


function draw(p: p5): void {
  p.background(255)

 const r: gridRange = {
        xrange: {
            min: -25,
            max: 25,
        },
        yrange: {
            min: -25,
            max: 25,
        },
    };

    setCoordinateSystem(r,p)
}

It works I have a frame with x between -25 and 25, y between -25 and 25 with x and y pointing rightwards and upwards respectively.
But when I add in draw code to write a text.
  p.text('test', -25, 0); 

rhe text in inverted. How can fix this problem.
The proposed solution from Thuong Vo works (probably I haven't tried it) but because I have a lot things to print I don't want call a function changing the coordinate of my objects every time. I want to change the coordinate systems one time only.


lot of code for nothing but at least it works
import p5 from "p5";

export const print = (p :p5, txt: string,wherex: number, wherey :number) => {
    p.scale(1, -1);
    p.textSize(10);
    p.text(txt, wherex, wherey);
    p.scale(1, -1);
}

or even better
import p5 from "p5";

export const print = (p :p5, txt: string,wherex: number, wherey :number) => {
    p.push();
    p.scale(1, -1);
    p.textSize(10);
    p.text(txt, wherex, wherey);
    p.pop();
}

and use
   print(p,"test",x,y)

instead of
   p.text("test", x, y);


I think the reason this is happening is that p.scale flips everything in the y-axis, which naturally flips the text as well. Instead, why not write a function that takes -25, 0 and transforms it to the correct point in the normal y axis pointing downwards style coordinates?
I think it would look something like this:
getCanvasCoords(r, x, y) {
    let xScalingCoeff = window.innerWidth / (r.xrange.max - r.xrange.min);
    let yScalingCoeff = window.innerHeight / (r.yrange.max - r.yrange.min) * -1;
    let xCenter = r.xrange.max;
    let yCenter = r.xrange.min;
    return [x * xScalingCoeff + xCenter, y * yScalingCoeff + yCenter];
}

const [x, y] = getCanvasCoords(r, -25, 0);
p.text("test", x, y);



Thanks for your answer but that is not really what I need for the reason I explained in the last paragraph of my question
